# Caliburn.Micro: How to change a Conductor<IScreen> to Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive

Tags: wpf, silverlight, caliburn.micro

I have a main viewmodel which is a `Conductor<IScreen>` in application and it seems to work fine. The corresponding view has a ContentControl called ActiveItem and this displays the ActiveItem which I can activate using ActivateItem on the viewmodel.

But I want to change this to a `Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive`. I thought at the basic level this would be a simple case of changing my viewmodel to:

```
public class MyViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
```

But this seems to break elements in the view (they just don't display)  Can anybody explain at a high level if there are other steps I may need to test this? Or what the effect of changing to the Collection implementation fo the Conductor has that may break other UI elements in my view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was fairly simple in the end:

The main thing that the collection implementations of the conductors add is an Items property. It turns out there was a UI element in my view also called Items, so I guess Caliburn.Micro was automatically binding this to the Items element in the view causing odd things to happen.  Renaming the UI element resolved this.